# What methods are there to identify brace/ curly bracket pairs in the Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Coming from a VB background I've wondered why I have as much difficulty structuring my c# as i do. I realised yesterday what one of the core differences between the two languages is. Take this example

```
If True Then
    While True
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            c = a + b
        Next
    End While
End If
```

It's clear where the scope of each block ends because

1. Matching indentation
2. Inside the IDE, clicking on an opening or closing brace highlights the other.
3. Closing statement matches opening statement (eg. While/ End While)

For the same code in c#

```
if (true) 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
        {
            c = a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

1 and 2 still apply but we've lost 3.

1. Matching indentation
2. Inside the IDE, clicking on an opening or closing statement highlights the other.

It seems like there should be features like automatic colour coding of braces.

What other strategies are available for keeping track of matching pairs of braces?

Comment: A win for VB's verbosity

Comment: In your VB code, change them to nested `If` statements, put a bunch of code in the middle and you still suffer the same problem. Remove the indentation for even more fun!

Comment: @DavidG - You can't remove indentation when coding in VB using Visual Studio (another win for VB)

Comment: @MattWilko Ah, it's been a long time since I've used VB! First point still stands though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the [VSCommands](http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/) "Code Block End Tagger" (note: despite not being mentioned on the website, it is also [available for VS 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6d1c265-7007-405c-a68b-5606af238ece)):

[image]

Options:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Put the cursor over a brace and hit CTRL+].  This will take yo to the matching brace.

Make sure you are consistent with your indents.

Answer (score 4):

There are various Visual Studio extensions that add lines and coloring for code blocks, like [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) and [Indent Guides](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30)

Of course, when you need this, you may have too many levels of indentation and might want to review and refactor your code.

Answer (score 3):

To identify the closing brace of a particular opening brace or vise verse. you can just place the cursor at the starting/ending of the brace then VS will automatically highlight the ending/starting brace. But with a very light color. To get notify easily you can change the color in

Tools ->Options ->Environment ->Fonts and Colors ->Display items ->Brace Matching(Rectangle) ->Item foreground, Select the color you want.